# Firebase Dynamic Links redirects to playstore even with app installed

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

I am trying to create firebase dynamic links that will redirect users to a specific page in my app. I managed to create the link and it works sometimes, but sometimes it will re-direct to the PlayStore even with the app installed. I am doing this in a physical Android device.

What I managed to understand is that if my browser app (Chrome) is open on the background of the device when I click the link (that is in an SMS or WhatsApp message) I am taken to the app (the behavior I want). It works consistently in this setup (different links, with my app open and closed in the background)

However, if I click the link and the browser app is not open in the background, it takes me to the PlayStore.

Here is the code I have to create the link:

```
Future<void> _createDynamicLink(bool short) async {
    final DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
      uriPrefix: 'https://myappname.page.link',
      link: Uri.parse('https://myappname/?gameCode=1111111'),
      androidParameters: AndroidParameters(
        packageName: 'com.last.myquarentineproject',
        minimumVersion: 0,
      ),
      dynamicLinkParametersOptions: DynamicLinkParametersOptions(
        shortDynamicLinkPathLength: ShortDynamicLinkPathLength.short,
      ),
      socialMetaTagParameters: SocialMetaTagParameters(
        title: 'Example Title',
        description: 'Example Description',
      ),
    );

    Uri url;
    if (short) {
      final ShortDynamicLink shortLink = await parameters.buildShortLink();
      url = shortLink.shortUrl;
    } else {
      url = await parameters.buildUrl();
    }
  }
```

And here is the code I use to get the link:

```
void initState() {
    handleDynamicLinks();
...
}

  void handleDynamicLinks() async {
    final PendingDynamicLinkData data = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
    _handleDeepLink(data);

    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(
        onSuccess: (PendingDynamicLinkData dynamicLink) async {
          _handleDeepLink(dynamicLink);
        }, onError: (OnLinkErrorException e) async {
      print('Link Failed: ${e.message}');
    });
  }

  void _handleDeepLink(PendingDynamicLinkData data) {
    final Uri deepLink = data?.link;
    if (deepLink != null) {
      receivedGameCode = deepLink.queryParameters['gameCode'];
      print('receivedGameCode: $receivedGameCode');
      print('_handleDeepLink | deeplink: $deepLink');
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/joingGame');

    } else { print('_handleDeepLink | deeplink: NO LINK'); }
  }
```

Any help is much appreciated!
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue on my end. I created dynamic link programmatically. I resolved it by providing the valid minimumVersion value.

```
androidParameters: AndroidParameters(
    packageName: 'com.example.myapp',
    minimumVersion: 24,
  ),
```

Also to handle dynamic link, once app open, I used

```
app_links: ^3.2.0
```

in Android Manifest file

```
       <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" tools:targetApi="m">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:host="myapp.page.link"/>
            <data android:scheme="https"/>
            <data android:scheme="http"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

I hope it will help